# Home page is not getting loaded

Tags: cors, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to setup Spartacus storefront first time. I have done setup commerce cloud 2005 as back-end application. I am able to access the page directly but I am not able to access the home page from Spartacus storefront. I also verified the CORS properties but couldn't find any missing one. Please find the attached screenshot for the error and suggest what is missing.

Error:

[Access Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9oF0.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a redirect on the preflight request.  That probably means that your Commerce instance is not configured to respond on that /rest/v2/basesites URL & is redirecting the response to another page (possibly hac login).

In 1905 and earlier, I would have suggested that this probably meant the cmsoccaddon was not properly installed.

However in 2005, it is more likely a different explanation - the OCC endpoints are on a slightly different address by default in 2005, as it will be setup using the updated version of OCC that comes with 2005.  In this case you should be accessing /occ/v2/basesites.

This is mentioned in one of the documentation pages, but is easy to overlook. See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/#check-appmodulets-for-base-url-and-other-settings in the *Spartacus Project Setup* section, there is a line relating to this:

> prefix: Defines the prefix to OCC calls; change /rest/v2/ to /occ/v2/
> if using release 2005

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is working after changing the prefix.